# ASP.NET Core gRPC JSON transcoding throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

I have a basic application and used the [gRPC JSON transcoding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/json-transcoding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article to incorporate gRPC JSON transcoding. However, when I try to run my application, it gives me an error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error binding gRPC service 'SomeGrpcService'.
 ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stored extension value has a type of 'Google.Api.HttpRule, Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. This a different from the requested type of 'Google.Api.HttpRule, Google.Api.CommonProtos, Version=2.5.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ec5ea7f18953e47'.
   at Google.Protobuf.ExtensionSet.Get[TTarget,TValue](ExtensionSet`1& set, Extension`2 extension)
   at Google.Protobuf.Reflection.MethodOptions.GetExtension[TValue](Extension`2 extension)
   at Grpc.Shared.ServiceDescriptorHelpers.TryGetHttpRule(MethodDescriptor methodDescriptor, HttpRule& httpRule)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding.Internal.Binding.JsonTranscodingProviderServiceBinder`1.AddMethod[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, UnaryServerMethod`2 handler)
   at WBD.Bolt.OneTimePassword.gRPC.API.PhoneOtpService.BindService(ServiceBinderBase serviceBinder, PhoneOtpServiceBase serviceImpl) in /.../obj/Debug/net7.0/SomeGrpc.cs:line 187
   at InvokeStub_PhoneOtpService.BindService(Object, Object, IntPtr*)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding.Internal.Binding.JsonTranscodingServiceMethodProvider`1.OnServiceMethodDiscovery(ServiceMethodProviderContext`1 context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding.Internal.Binding.JsonTranscodingServiceMethodProvider`1.OnServiceMethodDiscovery(ServiceMethodProviderContext`1 context)
   at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Model.Internal.ServiceRouteBuilder`1.Build(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.GrpcEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapGrpcService[TService](IEndpointRouteBuilder builder)
   at SomeApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in /.../SomeApplication/Program.cs:line 97
```

My setup is the following:
I have the following line in the *.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Protobuf Include="Protos\**\*.proto" ProtoRoot="Protos\" GrpcServices="Both" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and folder structure is:

```
Protos
  google
    api
      annotations.proto
      http.proto
  Some.proto
```

I believe the main issue is:

```
The stored extension value has a type of 'Google.Api.HttpRule, Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
This a different from the requested type of 'Google.Api.HttpRule, Google.Api.CommonProtos, Version=2.5.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3ec5ea7f18953e47'.
```

and I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding` version 7.0.9.

Can someone offer a solution to the problem mentioned above?

Comment: this seems like https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9626, which is marked completed - are you using up-to-date everythings?

Comment: @MarcGravell I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.JsonTranscoding@7.0.9 version with .NET 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change your directory like this:

```
  google
    api
      annotations.proto
      http.proto
  Protos
    Some.proto
```

[Project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpgz.png)

Comment: Hey you! Thank you for your contribution to the StackOverflow Community. Your answer was marked as correct. Congratulations! Please add some more information in the future to your answers so we can keep a very high standard on this platform.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes are fixed the issue for me:

update *.csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Protobuf Include="Protos\Some.proto" ProtoRoot="Protos\" GrpcServices="Both" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and added the `Google.Api.CommonProtos` library to the project.